# How to realize ON UPDATE CASCADE and ON DELETE CASCADE in Hibernate(JPA)?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have two tables: `Accounts` and `Mails`.

1 user from Accounts can have some mails (**1 : M ratationship**).

- When user is deleting his profile (from `Accounts`), hibernate should delete all mails for that user (from `Mails`). `Accounts` has id (PK) and other columns. `Mails` has id(PK), user_id(FK: user_id -> Accounts.id) and other columns.

How to achieve above kind of implementation on Hibernate (or JPA)?

My entity classes are as follows:

```
//Accounts class
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "accounts", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Mails> mails;

//Mails class
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id" , referencedColumnName="id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Accounts accounts;
```

But when I'm editing or deleting some parent rows, hibernate says: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails. So exactly where am I making ​​a mistake?

---

**UPDATE**

This error occurs when we execute SQL or HQL queries and it's not true. We should use entitymanager.remove or entitymanager.merge methods. My entity classes are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you have a bi-directional relation between account and mails. 
In the account class you have to use somethink like:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "accounts")  
private Set<Mails> mails;
```

Property mappedby is required for bi-directional. 
Hint: In my opinion you should only use bi-directional relations if it is really necessary.

Comment: Sorry I missed that you defined mappedBy already. Check insertable and updatable properties at mails class. also try to use nullable=false. You could also set property hibernate.show_sql to true in persistence.xml to see what sql is generated from merge or remove.